# Postgres server is not starting

Tags: postgresql, macos

I have installed postgres 11 earlier on my MacBook Pro. Suddenly it stopped working. Usually I start my postgres server by following command

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

and it returning the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.1_1/bin/postgres
  Reason: image not found
no data was returned by command ""/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.1_1/bin/postgres" -V"
The program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the
same directory as "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.1_1/bin/pg_ctl".
Check your installation.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

try to install\upgrade, Assuming you have Ubuntu on your machines then execute the following commands:

Upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install:

```
sudo apt install zsh
sudo apt-get install powerline fonts-powerline
```

If you have Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install zsh
```

MacOS

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

Comment: I am using Mac. I have just solved it by upgrading postgresql by `brew upgrade postgresql`

Comment: @Devil'sDream thanks for sharing how to fix it on MacOS. I will add the step to the answer to make it generalized,

Comment: Following worked for me for Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745770/10809622